# Swift: 'Int32' is not convertible to 'Int32'

Tags: ios, swift, ios8.1, xcode6.1.1

I'm in the middle of a project using `Swift 1.1` and `xCode 6.1.1`

I receive the following error when trying to make seconds out of a Value and Timescale

`PATH/ViewControllers/Camera/CaptureScreenViewController.swift:41:58: 'Int32' is not convertible to 'Int32'`

on the line following line

`var seconds = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(value),timescale)`

at `,timescale)`

Below are a few lines for reference

`var currentCellSegment = segmentForIndexPath(indexPath)
 var value = currentCellSegment.duration.value.value
 var timescale = currentCellSegment.duration.timescale.value
 var seconds = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(value),timescale)`

Any suggestions on how to fix? Or answers to why this is happening?

**Things I have tried**

I have already uninstalled xCode, restarted, and re-installed.

I've already tried to cast `timescale` `as Int32` like so

`var timescale = currentCellSegment.duration.timescale.value as Int32`

`var timescale: Int32 = currentCellSegment.duration.timescale.value`

`var timescale: Int32 = currentCellSegment.duration.timescale.value as Int32`

, but I receive the error on the line `var timescale...`

**as suggested by** @martin-r

*new reference code*

`var currentCellSegment = segmentForIndexPath(indexPath)
var value = currentCellSegment.duration.value
var timescale = currentCellSegment.duration.timescale
var seconds = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(value),timescale)`

**Solved**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is indeed a bit strange, but the solution is
probably to remove the unnecessary `.value` calls:

```
var value = currentCellSegment.duration.value
var timescale = currentCellSegment.duration.timescale
```

If `currentCellSegment.duration` is a `struct CMTime` then its
`timescale` property is a `CMTimeScale` aka `Int32`, and that is
what `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds()` expects.

---

The `value` property of `Int32` returns a `Builtin.Int32`, and that
causes the strange error message. Example:

```
func abc(x : Int32) {
    println(x)
}
let x = Int32(1)
abc(x)       // OK
abc(x.value) // error: 'Int32' is not convertible to 'Int32'
```

Comment: I receive the error - PATH/ViewControllers/Camera/CaptureScreenViewController.swift:41:21: Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '($T2, @lvalue CMTimeScale)' on the line var seconds... updating post

Comment: @MarkMasterson: You did not copy the first line correctly, only the *last* `.value` has to be removed.

Comment: Yup! Noticed that looking at the second error output. no more error! thanks